# Reverse engineering Objective-C blocks

Tags: ida, decompilation, ios, macos

I'm highly experienced with objective-c reverse engineering, but every time I encounter a block representation in the decompiler, right before it is passed as an argument to a function, I can intuitively understand it rather than actually get to know what each line in the code means.
For example, take a look at the following code:

```
v215[0] = (__int64)_NSConcreteStackBlock; // block declaration
v215[1] = 0xC0000000LL; // Have not idea what it means
v215[2] = (__int64)some_func_ptr; // the actual callback
v215[3] = (__int64)&unk_1000FDB78; // Have not idea what it means
v215[4] = (__int64)some_ns_object; // an argument to the underline function 
sub(arg1, arg2, v215) // a function that gets a block as an argument
```

Storing _NSConcreteStackBlock in v215[0], 0xC0000000LL in v215[1], some function pointer in v215[2], &unk_1000FDB78 (which is probably a struct pointer or some scalar pointer) in v215[3], and the rest of the block args in the following indices of v215 is a well known pattern that repeats itself whenever a block is declared.

But how does the arguments stored in the block are represented in the decompilation of some_function? and what are the meanings of 0xC0000000LL stored at v215[1] and  &unk_1000FDB78 stored at v215[3] ?

Thanks in advanced for you help !

Comment: I'm not "highly experienced with objective-c reverse engineering", but isn't that in IDA's help for the objective-c analysis plugin (https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1687.shtml). They also link here https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html, which gives you keywords that you can use to find the definition inside codegen/cgblocks.h from clang. The two unknown fields are flags and some descriptor. I'm guessing on this, but the closure's descriptor seems to contain some data necessary for managing the scope of its captured variables (including its size) depending on flags.